# Mopidy - exception in HttpFrontend

Tags: raspbian, mopidy

I installed Mopidy on my Raspbian. When I run mopidy, I get this error:

```
ERROR    Unhandled exception in HttpFrontend (urn:uuid:7dbd4827-d53d-49aa-9d2b-e12e46e7b196):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pykka/actor.py", line 200, in _actor_loop
    response = self._handle_receive(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pykka/actor.py", line 294, in _handle_receive
    return callee(*message['args'], **message['kwargs'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mopidy/http/actor.py", line 77, in on_event
    on_event(name, **data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mopidy/http/actor.py", line 84, in on_event
    handlers.WebSocketHandler.broadcast(message)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mopidy/http/handlers.py", line 93, in broadcast
    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'current'
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: sounds like you need to take that to developers of `mopidy`.

Comment: Hello! I am not sure whether this is Pi specific. Maybe try https://discuss.mopidy.com/ for more direct feedback concerning mopidy. Good thing is that this discuss thingy at mopidy seems quite active!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://discuss.mopidy.com/t/mopidy-1-0-1-doesnt-emit-events-over-ws-when-using-tornado-2-3/701/4 - short version is we forgot to test against Tornado 2.3 which is ancient.

I just pushed a fix for this which will be in a 1.0.2 bug fix release fairly soon.